# When i install the wordpress theme it shows me like this

Tags: wordpress, slider

What should i do to remove this bug or error ? 
I have downloaded the theme but when i install it,It actually shows this

> Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in
>   /customers/3/3/f/mabox-ks.com/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/amytheme/inc/update-notifier.php
>   on line 115
>
> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(http://themes.cray.bg/themeupdatesnotifier/amy.xml):
>   failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   Temporary failure in name resolution in
>   /customers/3/3/f/mabox-ks.com/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/amytheme/inc/update-notifier.php
>   on line 115
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /customers/3/3/f/mabox-ks.com/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/amytheme/inc/update-notifier.php:115)
>   in /customers/3/3/f/mabox-ks.com/httpd.www/wp-admin/includes/misc.php
>   on line 1114
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /customers/3/3/f/mabox-ks.com/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/amytheme/inc/update-notifier.php:115)
>   in
>   /customers/3/3/f/mabox-ks.com/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/amytheme/ReduxFramework/ReduxCore/framework.php
>   on line 2498
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /customers/3/3/f/mabox-ks.com/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/amytheme/inc/update-notifier.php:115)
>   in
>   /customers/3/3/f/mabox-ks.com/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/amytheme/ReduxFramework/ReduxCore/framework.php
>   on line 2499
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /customers/3/3/f/mabox-ks.com/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/amytheme/inc/update-notifier.php:115)
>   in
>   /customers/3/3/f/mabox-ks.com/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/amytheme/ReduxFramework/ReduxCore/framework.php
>   on line 2504
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /customers/3/3/f/mabox-ks.com/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/amytheme/inc/update-notifier.php:115)
>   in /customers/3/3/f/mabox-ks.com/httpd.www/wp-includes/pluggable.php
>   on line 1216

Comment: If you use a better title you can get better responds and more views, Read it if you want to ask better questions and get answers faster https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: can u help me or not ?

Comment: There are too many unknowns for anyone to post a meaningful or practical reply here. The smartest thing would be to contact the author of the theme.